# The inname parameter does not work with multiple parameters

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

I am trying to get details by passing semicolon delimited list in **inname** paramter but it is not working.

I tried below API call:

[https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/tags?order=desc&sort=popular&**inname=cocoa;objective-c**&site=stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/tags?order=desc&sort=popular&inname=cocoa;objective-c&site=stackoverflow)

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`inname` doesn't accept multiple parameters, it accepts a single substring which must be in the returned tags' names.